# SQL Query to select only Customers whose orders are ascending.(every new order bigger then previous)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I couldn't figure it out how to select only customers with ascending orders.

I have tables:

- customer (id, name)
- order (orderID, customerID)
- orderDetails (id, orderID, productID, quantity, orderDate)

Please help!

I was trying something like 2 selects, 1 ordered by date, and one ordered by quantity but couldn't manage to think about something useful.

Comment: some sample data and desired output would be a great help. And your attempted query too.

Comment: Additionally, can you explain what you mean by “ ascending orders”?